# Size of set of bounded vs unbounded sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lLgmDx8y70&index=9&list=PLAvgI3H-gclZa-DVTMyUIAxM-X8NSikwu) where an infinite set containing all bounded sequences is defined and I was wondering, which is a greater infinity, the set of all bounded sequences or the set containing all unbounded sequences?

Comment: The term "bounded sequence" is consistent both with the context "sequences in metric spaces" and with the less general context "numerical sequences which take values in $\Bbb R, \Bbb Q,\Bbb N$...". Could you please specify in what space the sequences take values (say, they are functions $\Bbb N\to\boxed{???}$)? I can't be bothered watching a 21-minute video to recover that information.

Comment: If it helps, the definition of bounded I meant is from http://www.u.arizona.edu/~mwalker/econ519/Econ519LectureNotes/Sequences.pdf, page 1 the first definition. 
This is the subset of bounded infinite sequences. I was wondering what is the complement of this set, in respect to all infinite sequences.

Comment: +1. This is a GREAT question. If there's no answers I might put a bounty. I looked at your profile and think you might be interested in Materials Modeling Stack Exchange. Bio-materials, solar cells, batteries, energy conversion materials, stronger glass, protein shapes, fabrics,stronger and lighter materials for cars, bikes, planes, spaceships, etc. Would you be so kind to commit to this? https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/122958/materials-modeling?referrer=ZTUyZWY5OTQ1NDI4ZGVlMmU5MzM0ZThiZjNhOTRkYWFlMTA1NjM0OWEzOTZhYzlmMTBlNWQ4ZmIzYWE3MWFkN-4At28O9gekwyERVbYPhFIPwyHiajfB5BeMyrZKJaYV0